# How can I make the height of a div section to automatically adapt to the height of its content?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a `div` container with `id=middle` that is centered in the page by this code:

```
header, #middle, footer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Inside the `div` named `middle` there are the `nav` and the `main` section.
The `div` is acting like a container for the `nav` and the `main`, so it should be easier to align the `nav` to the left and `main` to the right while keeping them centered.

I tried to do such alignment by the following code:

```
#middle {
    width: 849px;
    height: 600px; /*I wanto to set this to auto or get rid of it*/
}

nav {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

main {
    width: 649px;
    float: right;
}
```

It works, but I have to specify the height of `#middle`, **it doesn't automatically adapt** to the height of its content, messing up all the rest of the layout. In my site, the height of main and nav varies from page to page.

How can I fix this? I don't want to specify a fixed height for `#middle`, instead I would like that `#middle` varies its height depending on the maximum height between `main` and `nav`.

I don't know if it is useful but the CSS code ends with:

```
footer {
    width: 849px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

And this is the HTML code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
        <div id="middle">
            <nav>
                ...
            </nav>

            <main>
                ...
            </main>
        </div>
        <footer>
                ...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

N.B. `nav` and `main` are the semantic html5 tags, similar to `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<div>` with `clear: both;` after `</main>`. Then You can remove height of `#middle`